# trying to hide api but backend gives me error

Tags: javascript, express, next.js, backend

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfatX.png) I am trying to build nft search app that when you give adress it finds the nfts that a wallet has. but i am using alchemy and don't want to expose api key. Don't know backend, using next.js.

my backend code:

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;
  const owner = req.query.owner;
  const baseURL = `https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/nft/v2/${apiKey}/getNFTs/`;
  const fetchURL = `${baseURL}?owner=${owner}`;
  axios
    .get(fetchURL)
    .then((response) => {
      res.json(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.json({ error: error.message });
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

my frontend

```
 const fetchNFTs = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`/api?${wallet}`);
    const nfts = await response.json();
    setNFTs(nfts);
  };
```

I tried chat gpt, serverless function but I failed to achieve results

Comment: What error does the backend give you?

Comment: index.jsx?7ffd:12 
 GET http://localhost:3000/api?owner=0x83d0700d29854AAB1fB42165F97df4960dd82CA5 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I added an image to start of the post

Comment: Check the response, it's not returning valid JSON... based on the error, it's returning HTML.. make sure you're setting the response header from the API to `application/json`

Comment: how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a separate Express server? By default Next.js runs on port 3000, and that's why you're making a GET to `localhost:3000`. But if your Next.js server is started, your custom Express server would pick a different port because the 3000 is going to be taken. So your `const response = await fetch('/api?${wallet}');` will result in a 404 because there's no such route in your Next.js app.

You could move your function into a Next.js API handler if you want your backend and frontend to live under the same port. Also you wouldn't need to manually create the express server and take care of the dotenv since Next.js is going to take care of that for you.

Comment: Oh, ty. How could i move my function in to next.js api handler? I really don't know backend.

Comment: You can create a file `pages/api/nfts.js` and export a default async function like this:
```javascript
export default async function Api(req, res) {
   ...
}
```

If you want to pass the wallet, you could create a file like `pages/api/nfts/[wallet].js`, and obtain the wallet by doing `req.query.wallet`.

Next.js have a good documentation on their API routes here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

Comment: i manage to solve this by changing server to 3001

Comment: Great! Glad you solved your issue!